# Вытащить текст из span'а, который лежит в другом span'е

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup, bs4

Мне нужно распарсить страницу (https://darksky.net/details/55.7415,37.6156/2020-6-12/ca12/en) и вытащить от туда все градусы. Проблема в том, что все это лежит в двойном span'e и в блоке с классом "temps". BeautifulSoup просто не может найти их. Что делать в таком случае?

Вот часть страницы:

```html
  <div class="temps">
        <span class="first" style="opacity: 0.88331; left: 1px;">
            <span>22°</span>
        </span>
        <span style="opacity: 0.734795; left: 66.6667px;">
            <span>21°</span>
        </span>
        <span style="opacity: 0.605375; left: 133.333px;">
            <span>19°</span>
        </span>
        <span style="opacity: 0.669024; left: 200px;">
            <span>20°</span>
        </span>
        <span style="opacity: 0.841938; left: 266.667px;">
            <span>22°</span>
        </span>
        <span style="opacity: 0.975601; left: 333.333px;">
            <span>23°</span>
        </span>
        <span style="opacity: 0.867397; left: 400px;">
            <span>22°</span>
        </span>
        <span style="opacity: 0.881188; left: 466.667px;">
            <span>22°</span>
        </span>
        <span style="opacity: 0.950141; left: 533.333px;">
            <span>23°</span>
        </span>
        <span style="opacity: 0.924682; left: 600px;">
            <span>22°</span>
        </span>
        <span style="opacity: 0.583098; left: 666.667px;">
            <span>19°</span>
        </span>
        <span style="opacity: 0.364569; left: 733.333px;">
            <span>17°</span>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Вот мой код, который не ищет даже первый span с классом first:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://darksky.net/details/55.7415,37.6156/2020-6- 12/ca12/en')

if response.status_code == 200:
    html_doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='html.parser')
    list_of_values = html_doc.find('span', {'class': 'first'})

    print(list_of_values)
```

Comment: Это ищется достаточно элементарно с помощью css-селекторов. Покажите свой код, я укажу на вашу ошибку. Кнопка "править" под текстом вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Для поиска таких вложений нужно использовать более сложные селекторы. Например:

```py
list_of_values = html_doc.find('span > span')
```

в списке `list_of_values`  окажется перечень элементов с искомыми данными

Comment: Увы, но даже так приходит просто None

Comment: подозреваю, что данные формируются и выводятся после загрузки страницы средствами ajax и javascript. В этом случае вам bs не поможет. Нужно смотреть в сторону управления браузерами, а не парсеров статичных html